# How to Modify Wordpress Plugin Placement/Position on Post Page?

Tags: plugins

I'm new to Wordpress and I have some background in PHP and programming. I installed a Wordpress theme and some plugins which all work fine. However, on my Post page, I have 3 plugins being displayed one after the other at the end of the blog post.

Now, I can't seem to find how those plugins "decide" to be in that position the are in. Let's say I have the 3 plugins A, B, C in that order being shown by Default. In which file to I go to show them as B, C, A?

Comment: What do you mean by "3 plugins being displayed"? Plugins are pieces of code that do something (like displaying stuff), they don't just show up on your post page. Or are you talking about widgets?

Comment: @Michael I mean plugins. So let's say I install a Social Plugin that display the share buttons on the post page. It shows up at a specific location on that page by default. Now let's say I want to change it's placement on that specific page, where do I find the code to change the placement?

Comment: If it's not using a widget to display, you need to find the specific template file which most likely lives in the root folder of your theme.

Comment: I see. So plugins in general, inject their code to the specific template file, correct?

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question, because it's way too general. "Plugins" do a million things, but a convenient way to control the placement of snippets of functionality in the frontend is to use widgets. W/o looking at your template files, nobody will be able to tell you anything specific.

Comment: @Castiblanco seriously, one comma added? another archaeologist who has reached 2k reputation points?